# Why does changing the order of how I define my neural network layers change the out come?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

So I have a Neural Network that looks like

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size,  num_layers1, num_layers2, num_layers3, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.num_layers1 = num_layers1
        self.num_layers2 = num_layers2
        self.num_layers3 = num_layers3
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size 

        self.transformer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=100, nhead=20, layer_norm_eps=1e-04, dropout=0.3, dim_feedforward=2048, norm_first=True, activation= "relu", batch_first=True)

        self.fc1_bn = nn.BatchNorm1d(125)
        self.conv1 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose1d(in_channels=125, out_channels=125, kernel_size=6)   
        self.layerNorm = torch.nn.LayerNorm(7)

        self.drop2 = torch.nn.Dropout(DROPOUT2)  
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.ConvTranspose1d(in_channels=125, out_channels=125, kernel_size=5)   
        self.layerNorm2 = torch.nn.LayerNorm(512)

        self.maxpool1d = nn.LPPool1d( 1,1)
        self.fc2_bn= nn.BatchNorm1d(125)

        self.lstm2 = nn.LSTM(200, hidden_size, num_layers2, batch_first=True ,dropout = .2 ) 

        #
        #self.maxpool1d2 = nn.LPPool1d( 1,1)          
        self.lstm3 = nn.LSTM(hidden_size, hidden_size, num_layers3, batch_first=True  )
        self.drop3 = torch.nn.Dropout(DROPOUT3)


        self.lstm4 = nn.LSTM(200, 200, num_layers3, batch_first=True  )
        
         
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)    

        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 200)   
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(205, 200)   
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512, 512)   
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(3, 100)  


    def forward(self, x):
        h02 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) 
        c02 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers2, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) 
        h03 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers3, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) 
        c03 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers3, x.size(0), self.hidden_size).to(device) 

        #out = self.conv1(x)

        out = F.relu(self.fc5(x))
        out = self.transformer(out)
        out = F.relu(self.fc2(out))
        #out = self.fc1_bn(out)
        
        

        out = self.conv1(out)
        out = F.relu(self.fc3(out))
        out = self.maxpool1d(out)
        
        
        out, _ = self.lstm2(out, (h02,c02))
        out = F.relu(self.fc4(out)) 
        #out = self.fc1_bn(out)

        out, _ = self.lstm3(out, (h03,c03))   

        out = out[:, -1, :]    
        out = self.fc(out)       
        return out
```

If I change the order of anything in the def **init** the accuracy changes by a lot. If I leave it the same the accuracy doesn't change at all. Why is this? I thought that's just were you define the modules of your neural network? So if i'm just defining them there and not using them in that part of the Neural Network then why does this happen?

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of a proposed change that affects the accuracy?

Comment: Moving anything in that init changes the accuracy it doesn't matter what it is. So if i moved all the fc layers to above self.transformer, it goes from about 60% accuracy to 25%. Even if I have unused stuff in the INIT it will change the accuracy.

Comment: Are you setting a seed?

Comment: yes with torch.manual_seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)